# How to add meta description/title to contact page in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

The contact page of my site is https://example.com/contact_us . On google, it shows like

which is not very good. 
It seems there is no way to edit from admin panel the meta title and meta description of this page. neither on theme panel.
So, how to edit this from core files?

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/contact.tpl
```

seems not having any related, and don't see a way to edit loading header just for this one page

can you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope it's 100% working for you.**

Find the controller Path of Page. you wish to edit and then do the below,

> PATH : catalog\controller\information\contact.php

Find:

```
$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
```

Add After:

```
$this->document->setDescription('My description, this is where i type my text after i remove this text.');
$this->document->setKeywords('my, keyword, this, is, the place, holder, for, my, keywords');
```